# Sanitizing Trix input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, trix

Under Rails 5.1 I am using Trix to allow users to edit their 'legal conditions'. Then I am trying to sanitize this 'legal' parameter in my controller before the user record is updated, but end up with :

```
undefined method `sanitize'
```

Here the code :

```
params[:user][:legal] = sanitize params[:user][:legal], tags: %w(strong div strong br li ul)

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:presentation, :linktowebsite, :legal)
end
```

Don't see anything different than normal usage shown here : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `sanitize` correctly. `sanitize` is used in the view, not in the controller.

To use it correctly, your model should allow a field to save html input from the user, but you want to "clean" it when it's used in the view so that unsafe or non-whitelisted tags/attributes is prevented from being sent/displayed to the user.

If you are looking to remove html tags/attributes before it gets saved, you may want to look at [strip_tags](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags).

```
strip_tags("Strip <i>these</i> tags!")
# => Strip these tags!

strip_tags("<b>Bold</b> no more!  <a href='more.html'>See more here</a>...")
# => Bold no more!  See more here...

strip_tags("<div id='top-bar'>Welcome to my website!</div>")
# => Welcome to my website!
```